# how to reset the focus to last entered textbox in windows application

Tags: c#

I have two `TextBox`es and a button control in the form. When the button is clicked the name of the last entered `TextBox` should be displayed in a `MessageBox`. At the same time I need to reset the focus to last entered `TextBox`.

```
string str=string.Empty;
bool foc;
```

In button click I wrote the following code

```
    if (MessageBox.Show("You want to reset or continue", "control", 
           MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) == DialogResult.Cancel)
    {
        if (foc== true)
        {
            textBox1.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            textBox2.Focus();
        }
    }
```

When I clicks on cancel button the focus should be into textbox which is entered at last

```
    private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        str = textBox1.Name;
        foc= textBox1.Focus();
    }

    private void textBox2_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        str= textBox2.Name;
        foc= false;
    }
```

Other than the above lines of code is there any other possibility to focus into the textbox, but when number of textboxes increases how i need to write the conditions.
If I am having textbox,combobox,listbox,checkbox or any other controls in the form then how to find in which control the user enterd at last and set focus to that control by using any function instead of writing in every control Enter event

Answer (score 1):

You can handle `Leave` event of the `TextBoxes` to store the Last `TextBox` Control.

Try this:

```
    this.btnSubmit.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Submit_Click);
    this.btnCancel.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Cancel_Click);
    this.textBox1.Leave += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_Leave);
    this.textBox2.Leave += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox2_Leave);
    TextBox txtLast = new TextBox();


    private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        txtLast = (TextBox)sender;
    }
    private void textBox2_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        txtLast = (TextBox)sender;
    }
    private void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(txtLast.Text);
    }

    private void Cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtLast.Focus();
    }
```

Comment: If I am having textbox,combobox,listbox,checkbox or any other controls in the form then how to find in which control the user enterd at last  and set focus to that control by using any function instead of writing in every control leave event

Answer (score 0):

```
 public bool textBox1WasLastFocused = false, textBox2WasLastFocused = false; // Global Declaration
 void textBox2_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    textBox2WasLastFocused = true;
    textBox1WasLastFocused = false;
 }

 void textBox1_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     textBox1WasLastFocused = true;
     textBox2WasLastFocused = false;
 }

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (textBox1WasLastFocused)
        MessageBox.Show("textbox1 was ladst focused !");
     else if(textBox2WasLastFocused)
        MessageBox.Show("textbox2 was ladst focused !");
 }
```